# Check if numpy array has a normal shape

Tags: python, numpy

How do I check if a `numpy` array has a *regular* shape.

In the example below `x` is a `*2 by 3*` matrix. However `y` is not regular in the sense that it can't be represented as a proper matrix.

Given that I have a `numpy` array, is there a method (preferably in-built) that I can use to check that the `numpy` array is an actual matrix

```
In [9]: import numpy as np                                                      

In [10]: x = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])                                        

In [11]: x.shape                                                                
Out[11]: (2, 3)

In [12]: y = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5]])                                          

In [13]: y.shape                                                                
Out[13]: (2,)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are arrays and those are valid shapes. But, with *normal*, think you meant that each element has the same shape and length across it. For that, a better way would be to check for the datatype. For the variable length case, it would be `object`. So, we can check for that condition and call out accordingly. Hence, simply do -

```
def is_normal_arr(a): # a is input array to be tested
    return a.dtype is not np.dtype('object')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the .shape method is capable of checking it.
If you input an array which can form a matrix it returns it's actual shape, `(2, 3)` in your case. If you input an incorrect matrix it returns something like `(2,)`, which says something's wrong with the second dimension, so it can't form a matrix.

Comment: replace "correct/incorrect array" with "correct/incorrect matrix". All of them are correct arrays ;)

Comment: Yes, true. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here `y` is a one-dimensional array and the size of `y` is 2. `y` contains 2 `list` values.
AND `x` is our actual matrix in a proper format.

check the dimensions by `y.ndim` AND `x.ndim`.