# Checking if a numpy array has the same number of elements across its length and width

Tags: python, numpy

Given a numpy array, what is the best way to check if it has the same number of elements across its length and width? So for example, in the following arrays,

```
arr1 = np.array([[0,1],[2,3],[4,5]])
arr2 = np.array([1,2,None,4])
arr3 = np.array([1,2,3,[4,5]])
```

`arr1`, `arr2` are OK but `arr3` is not OK.

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57725450/check-if-numpy-array-has-a-normal-shape) partially answers my question but it doesn't quite work because it will say `arr2` is not OK because it has `None`.

Comment: do your arrays always contain integers or floats?

Comment: `arr1` is (3,2) `int` dtype.  `arr2` is (4,) object dtype.  `arr3` is (2,) object dtype, with "ragged" warning.  For optimal `numpy` use, only `arr1` is OK.

Comment: What's your understanding of `matrices`?  Or to put it another way, how do you intend to use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a piece of code cleverly using try-except to check the required conditions. (This should cover all cases of numerical data). `.astype(float)` is able to handle None and it converts it to nan. `list` is not handled by it, so we can use that to differentiate.

```
def check_arr(array):
    try:
        array = array.astype(float)
        return "OK"
    except:
        return "not OK"
arr1 = np.array([[0,1],[2,3],[4,5]])
arr2 = np.array([1,2,None,4])
arr3 = np.array([1,2,3,[4,5]])

print(f"arr1 is {check_arr(arr1)}")
print(f"arr2 is {check_arr(arr2)}")
print(f"arr3 is {check_arr(arr3)}")
```

Output:

```
arr1 is OK
arr2 is OK
arr3 is not OK
```

A better way would be to do this:

```
def check_arr(array):
    return "not OK" if array.dtype==object else "OK"
```

but this won't work in your case as a valid case in your example has the NoneType value, which makes the array datatype `object`. I would suggest you use `np.nan` and float arrays instead of `None` in general for such cases.